# Compare two date times

Tags: vb6

`label1` displays the last transaction date/time which I get from a database through a query. `label2` is the system date/time. I have a timer that executes a command button after which I want to check if the date/time in label1 is smaller than 5 minutes. If so then I want to show a massage.

But I don’t know why my code is failing to perform this function.
Any help will be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim date1 As Date
    Dim date2 As Date

    date1 = Format(Now, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss")
    date2 = Format(label1, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss")
    If DateDiff("n", date1, date2) < 2 Then
       MsgBox ("Not Vending")
    End If
End Sub
```

I've also tried:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim date1 As Date
    Dim label1 As Date

    date1 = Format(Now, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss")
    date2 = label1
    If DateDiff("m", Now, date1) > DateDiff("m", Now, label1) Then
       MsgBox ("Not Vending")
    End If
End Sub
```

As well as:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()  
    If DateDiff("n", Now, label1) > 5 Then
       MsgBox ("Not Vending")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where does label1 come from?  Why are you converting date types to strings only to go and call DateDiff on the strings (which forces it convert the strings back to Dates)??  Giving us multiple versions of Command1_Click isn't helpful, show us just one that is closest to what you think should work.

Answer (score 3):

If the date pulled from the DB is earlier than Now, DateDiff will always return a negative number if you pass Now as the second parameter.  It looks like you're checking for the passage of time, so I'll assume the dates in DB will always be before Now.  You need to switch the order of Now and the date to which it is being compared (`DateDiff("n", date1, Now)` instead of `DateDiff("n", Now, date1)`.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim date1 As Date
    date1 = CDate(Label1.Caption)
    If DateDiff("n", date1, Now) < 5 Then
       MsgBox ("Not Vending")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Raven's code should work for you. For debugging purposes I would add and Else to the statement such as Else MsgBox DateDiff("n", date1, Now) & " minutes difference"

Comment: Thanks for the reply got it sorted.

Answer (score 2):

An other way without using the `DateDiff`-function would be direct calculation with the `Date`-variables - since under the hood these are actually `Doubles`.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim date1 As Date
    date1 = CDate(Label1.Caption)
    '#12:05:00 AM# is representing a value of 5 Minutes in the Date-datatype
    If (date1 - Now) < #12:05:00 AM# Then
       MsgBox ("Not Vending")
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to check the time difference you can also use

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim date1 As Date
    date1 = CDate(Label1.Caption)
    '#12:05:00 AM# is representing a value of 5 Minutes in the Date-datatype
    If Abs(date1 - Now) < #12:05:00 AM# Then
       MsgBox ("Not Vending")
    End If
End Sub
```

Where `Abs(date1 - Now)` returns the time difference as `Date`-value

Btw. `date1 = Format(Now, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss")` doesn't make sence. Since `Now` returns a `Date`-value, `Format` converts that `Date`-value into a `String` and assigning it to `date1` converts that `String` back to a `Date`-value ùsing the local system settings for date formats - which means that the program will behave different on different systems.