# VB6 - Expiration Date Logic

Tags: vb6

The code I wrote in VB6 is to check if the expiration date is still earlier than now, hence the product isn't expired. Otherwise, the product is expired. However, the product's details are always reused in the system.

So, my code is this:

```
Global database As Database
Global recordset As Recordset
Dim intResponse As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()
Set database = OpenDatabase("C:\Location\Database.mdb")
Set recordset = database.OpenRecordset("Table")
recordset.Index("PrimaryKey")
End Sub

Private Sub txtProductID_LostFocus()
If txtProductID <> "" Then
    recordset.Seek "=", txtProductID
    If recordset.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox("Record not found!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Record not found")
        txtProductID = ""
        txtProductID.SetFocus
    Else
        If recordset("Expiration_Date") > DateValue(Now) Then
            Enable_Details ' Sub Function
        Else
            intResponse = MsgBox("Product is expired!", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Product is Expired")
            If intResponse = vbOK Then
                frmNewExpiryDate.Show
            End If 
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

When I debug the code, I cross-reference with the database and noticed that even if some products are expired, the code directly goes to Enable_Details sub. I need help!

Comment: Maybe this link can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004788/compare-two-date-times

Comment: @user3848226 what does the datediff return? and which value tells if the current date is behind or beyond the expiry date?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
Dim sDate as date
sDate = format(recordset("Expiration_Date"),"mm/dd/yyyy")
if datediff("d",Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy"),sDate) < 0 then
'already expired
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the database field "*Expiration_Date*"? is it a *String* or is it a *Date*? If the type is a *String*, then you'll need to convert it to a *Date* by splitting up the string and using **DateSerial**, and if it IS a *Date*, the code should work.
So I think the actual type is a *String* and therefore it won't work.

Also just use *recordset("Expiration_Date") >* **Date**  rather than *recordset("Expiration_Date") >*  **DateValue(Now)**, although both do exactly the same, but **Date** is more optimized.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function IsExpiry() As Boolean

IsExpiry = False

'set your expiry date here
ExpiryYear = 2017
ExpiryMonth = 10
ExpiryDay = 10


    If Year(Date) > ExpiryYear Then
        IsExpiry = True
        GoTo last
    End If

    If Month(Date) > ExpiryMonth Then
         IsExpiry = True
         GoTo last
    End If


    If Month(Date) = ExpiryMonth Then
        If Day(Date) > ExpiryDay Then
            IsExpiry = True
            GoTo last
        End If
    End If

last:
End Function



Private Sub cmdCheckExpiry_Click()

  If IsExpiry then
     MsgBox("Expired")
  Else
     MsgBox("Not Expired")
  Endif

End Sub
```